# Get the FPDF_Document handler of an output pdf file by a path

Tags: java, pdf, document, fpdf

I want to exact some pages from a pdf file to a new one, I create a new pdf file in Java side, its path is /data/data/com. .../newone.pdf, and I pass this path to native code, password is "", I run the code below the _docDst is NULL, I don't know why, is it because the file is empty or I just simply named its extension as pdf but it is not a pdf file, anyone who can help?

```
auto _docDst = FPDF_LoadDocument(dstPath,password);
```

Comment: You should make a copy of the file locally and find out the answer to your question "is it because the file is empty or I just simply named its extension as pdf but it is not a pdf file".  I'm not sure how we could possibly know the answer?